# Set User-agent on a SOAP webservice in WP7/Silverlight

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, http-headers, user-agent

I'm attempting to set the user-agent to something meaningful on my SOAP asynchronous requests in C#.

This is what I'm doing now to establish the connection:

```
BasicHttpBinding bind = new BasicHttpBinding();
bind.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
_proxyIdentify = new MembershipServiceContractClient(bind, new EndpointAddress(App.membershipServiceEndpoint));

_proxyIdentify.IdentifyCompleted += new EventHandler<IdentifyCompletedEventArgs>(proxyMembership_IdentifyCompleted);
_proxyIdentify.IdentifyAsync(_userName);
```

Any ideas from here on how I would go about adding the useragent ot the header? I can't really seem to find anything on how to accomplish this.